# GRPC in Java cause exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [h2]

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, grpc, okhttp, grpc-java

I'm using Spring Cloud and try request to web3 nodes with GRPC, but I got following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [h2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Here is my coding:

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = OkHttpChannelBuilder
                .forTarget("grpc.osmotest5.osmosis.zone:443")
                .useTransportSecurity()
                .build();

ServiceGrpc.ServiceBlockingStub serviceStub = ServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(managedChannel);
Query.GetNodeInfoRequest request = Query.GetNodeInfoRequest.newBuilder().build();
Query.GetNodeInfoResponse response = serviceStub.getNodeInfo(request);
System.out.println(response);
```

The strange thing is, it worked on my own laptop, but cause exceptions when I upload it to AWS cloud service (running in k8s), it might be problems related to the container.

Does anyone met similar problems and could give me some insight on how to solve this?
Thanks you so much.

Comment: Could you please paste the full stacktrace? This slice of it doesn’t indicate where the exception was originally thrown.

Comment: The error means HTTP/2 could not be negotiated. If you used the same client build locally, then the problem is probably a different server-side. There is probably a proxy or similar that isn't configured for HTTP/2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved the problem related to the different versions of `OpenSSL` on my local machine and the remote container's image. After upgrading the version from `1.0.1t (2016) to 1.1.1n (2022)`, everything worked fine.

The reason might be that GRPC is over HTTP2 and requires a TLS handshake, some servers with the latest version of OpenSSL do not accept outdated TLS algorithms from the clients side.